# ¿Cómo hacer que mi cámara tenga un zoom inicial en un objeto y decrezca dicho zoom en Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, cámara, zoom

Tengo el siguiente código que hace que la cámara siga a un objeto:

```
public class Camarita : MonoBehaviour {

public Material[] materials;
    public Renderer rend;

    private int index = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        rend.enabled = true;

    }

    public void pulsar() {
        if (materials.Length == 0) {
            return;
        }
            index += 1;

            if (index == materials.Length + 1) {
                index = 1; 
            }
            print (index);

            rend.sharedMaterial = materials [index - 1];                        

    }
}
```

Pero necesito que se centre con un zoom digamos por ejemplo al 300% en el objeto, es decir, que solo en la escena se vea el objecto al estar tan cerca la cámara y que inmediatamente se aleje y se vea toda la escena.

He intentado poner camera.fieldOfView en `Start` porque es lo que hace el zoom pero no me deja, no lo lee y buscando info no hablan de hacer nada parecido... ¿cómo se haría? ¿ Es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.
Primero, me parece que el script que has compartido no hace lo que tu piensas que hace. Ese script no hace que la cámara siga a ningún objeto.

Para que la cámara siga a un objeto, puedes hacerlo de multiples formas, aquí tienes un par de sitios donde explican dos metodos muy completos para hacerlo, con codigo fuente incluido:

- https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-ufo-tutorial/following-player-camera
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/38526/smooth-follow-camera.html

Para lo que dices del Zoom, es cierto que puedes hacerlo modificando el Field Of View (FOV) de la cámara una vez que tengas implementado cualquiera de estos dos métodos, pero puede que el resultado sea mejor si lo haces modificando la distancia de la cámara al objeto perseguido. Prueba con ambas formas y así ves cual da mejor resultado para tu proyecto.

Comment: Hola, sí , puse mal el script, pero el de seguir sí que lo tengo bien implementado. Respecto a lo del zoom, se puede enfocar y despues irte para atrás con la camara? probaré! y te comento, gracias.

Comment: Antonio, de todas formas he encontrado el FOV pero gráficamente creo que no se puede hacer, lo has logrado alguna vez?